# convert mp4 video to bytearray as3

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, video, air, arrays

I am trying to upload a video to Facebook from an air for android app. the as3 facebook api has the following method for uploading videos 
`facebookMobile.uploadVideo(method:String, callback:Function = null, params:* = null)`

`params:* (default = null) — An object containing the title, description, fileName (including extension), and video (FileReference or ByteArray)`

i am recording the video using cameraUi and am getting back the location of the file. according to the api i need to pass in this file using either `fileReferance` or a `byteArray` as i already have the location of the file i don't want any sort of browse functionality. I am having trouble creating the `byteArray` (never used it before). i am getting a 353 error from facebook: `you must select a video file`.

Bellow is my attempt at creating the bytearray

```
    public function UICompleteHandler(event:MediaEvent):void
    {
        trace("Welcome back from the camera");

        var media:MediaPromise = event.data;
        trace("file info "+media.file.url  + " - " + media.relativePath + " - " + media.mediaType);
        filePath = media.file.url;

        trace("Object encoding is: " + inBytes.objectEncoding + "\n\n" + "order file: \n\n");
        readFileIntoByteArray(filePath, inBytes); 
        trace("length 1:   "+inBytes.length);
        trace("position 1: "+inBytes.position);
        inBytes.position = 0; // reset position to beginning 
        //inBytes.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.DEFLATE); 

        //trace("position 2:  "+inBytes.position);
        //inBytes.position = 0;    //reset position to beginning 
        trace (inBytes);

    }
    private function readFileIntoByteArray(fileName:String, data:ByteArray):void 
    { 
        var inFile:File = new File(fileName);
        trace ("file to byte array  "+  inFile.url);
        trace ("file name var : "+fileName);

        inStream.open(inFile , FileMode.READ);
        inStream.readBytes(data); 
        inStream.close();           
    }
```

and video upload code:

```
    public function handleUpload(ev:TouchEvent)
    {
        trace ("posting to facebook - FileName: "+  accessCamera.fileName + " - FilePath: " + accessCamera.filePath);
        var params:Object ={  
            title:'test upload on FB api',
            description:'test upload on FB api',
            fileName: accessCamera.fileName,
            video: accessCamera.inBytes
        }

        //trace ("params.video = "+params.video);

        FacebookMobile.uploadVideo('me/videos', onComplete, params);
    }

    private function onComplete( result:Object, fail:Object ):void {
        trace("facebook post onComplete called" );
        if (result)
        {
            //result.id is id of post that was just posted
            trace ("great");
        }
        else if (fail)
        {
            trace("post Failed");  
            trace('code: '+fail.error.code); 
            trace('message: '+fail.error.message);
            trace('type: '+fail.error.type); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert it to a `ByteArray`. `File` is an AIR-only class meant to allow you to access the file system directly (as you already are doing). As `File` extends `FileReference`, you can simply pass the `File` object you already have instead.